# Relational db how to store complex logical relations?

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database, logical-operators

For example, we have a system that lets user claim X amount of gifts base on the events they joined.

event table:

```
| id | name    |
----------------
| A  | event A |
| B  | event B |
```

gift table:

```
| id | name | formula   |
--------------------------
| 1  | dog  | A*1 + B*2 |
| 2  | cat  | (A|B)*3   |
```

In the gift table we have some formulas:

- **`A*1 + B*2`** - User joined event A can get 1 toy, if they joined event B, they can get another 2 toy.
- **`(A|B)*3`** - User joined either event A or B can get 3 toys.

Formulas are evaluated in the backend, but I'm wondering whether we can represent the relation of `event` and `gift` in the database somehow? Specifically, we'd like to:

1. `SQL SELECT` `event` base on `gift`, and vice versa
2. keep track of number of times users claimed a `gift` base on each `event`.

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a many-to-many relationship tables for relation between gift and event as well as claims to gifts by users:

```
CREATE TABLE event_gifts
(
  id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  event_id text REFERENCES event(id),
  gift_id int REFERENCES gift(id)
);

CREATE TABLE event_gift_claim
(
   id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   user_id INT REFERENCES user(id),
   event_gift_id INT REFERENCES event_gifts (id)
);
```

Then you can track relationships between event and gifts:

```
INSERT INTO event_gifts (event_id, gift_id)
VALUES 
   ('A', 1),
   ('A', 2),
   ('B', 1),
   ('B', 2);
```

And select the events that award a certain gift:

```
SELECT event.*
  FROM event
  JOIN event_gifts
    ON event_gifts.event_id = event.id
  JOIN gift
    ON gift.id = event_gifts.gift_id
 WHERE gift.name = 'dog'
```

(or the other way around, gifts from events)

You can track who claimed what:

```
INSERT INTO event_gift_claim (user_id, event_gift_id) VALUES 
(1, 1), -- User1: dog from A
(1, 2), -- User1: cat from A
(2, 1), -- User2: dog from A
(2, 2), -- User2: cat from A
(2, 3), -- User2: dog from B
(2, 4)  -- User2: cat from B
```

If you have an attendance table like `user_events` and claiming a gift is not optional then you wouldn't need `event_gift_claim` because you can derive what was claimed from the attendance table.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a bridging table ([associative entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity)) that logs which users have been to which events. This would look like the following:

`User_Events`:

```
User_ID | Event_ID
------------------
1       | 1
1       | 2
2       | 2
```

Note that each value represents a foreign key (`id`) in the relevant table.

From here, you can apply your logic based on 'events that the user has been to', by querying something like:

```
SELECT E.*
FROM Users U
JOIN Events E
  ON User_Events.User_ID = User_Events.Event_ID
```